# Salesforce Rest API - overcoming Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue

Tags: rest, salesforce

I have a relatively simple Rest API class in Apex. Given an Id, the doGet method retrieves the record in question.

```
@HttpGet
global static VendorCostWrapper doGet() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    VendorCostWrapper response = new VendorCostWrapper();

    String vcId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    findVendorCost(res, response, vcId);

    res.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    return response;
}
```

This works like a champ when I call it from the Salesforce Workbench app. Unfortunately, when I try calling the endpoint from a Visualforce page using Angular like this:

```
$scope.restTest = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '/services/apexrest/v1/vendorcosts/a0J8A000000VdQm',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer {!GETSESSIONID()}'
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

I get the dreaded "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." error. I was hoping that my res.addHeader(...) line in the class would take care of this problem, but alas, it has not. Where have I gone astray?

Comment: UPDATE: So, when I tried running this test in Edge (stop laughing), it worked fine. So this is likely then a security issue that Chrome has in place that the MS flavoured browsers do not.

Comment: UPDATE 2: Works fine also in Firefox.